# What is the glowing paper-thin material inside a flat night light?

Tags: light

I opened up a night light that sits flat against the wall (only about 1/4" thick).  It is basically a flat square that plugs directly into the receptacle.  Inside, I found a paper-thin material that looks black on one side and a silver on the other.  The silver side lights up a soft glowing green color when it is connected.

What is this material, and where can I get a larger quantity of it?

Comment: Without seeing it, I would say it's a LED with light-transmitting material, like a glass.

Comment: Please add a picture.

Comment: Can you also provide a product part number for the night light? As mentioned, a picture is also necessary.

Comment: Night light model 99905.  It is definitely electroluminescent like Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an [electrolumiscent (EL) panel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroluminescence#Practical_implementations). It comes in various colors, sizes, and shapes, including a [wire-like form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroluminescent_wire).

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 I'm a bit surprised these are still around, but the blue-green light is a dead giveaway.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany EL is very hot in pop-DIY right now, in all shapes, sizes and types.